# How to replace "android:drawableLeft" image in CheckedTextView

Tags: android, android-layout, checkedtextview

I set image icon in layout using  "android:drawableLeft". This is my layout code:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="left"/>
```

What I need to do is, change this image into something else using my class. This is the code I used inside my Adapter class which is extend with BaseExpandableListAdapter.

```
if (convertView == null) {
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_details, null);
}
((CheckedTextView) convertView).setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.ic_folder);
```

But this is not replace the used image. Instead replacing it is added to the same line. What should I do to replace the current image with the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did as the solution for the problem. Hope it will help anyone who faced the same problem. Here parent is ViewGroup parameter,

```
Drawable imageDrawable=parent.getContext().getResources().getDrawable((R.drawable.ic_folder));
 imageDrawable.setBounds(0,0, 40, 40);
((CheckedTextView) convertView).setCompoundDrawables(imageDrawable, null,null, null);
```

Answer (score 5):

In your xml you are using

```
`android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"`
```

and in adapter you are doing

```
((CheckedTextView) convertView).setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.ic_folder);
```

These are two different features of CheckedTextView . CheckMark drawable and drawable are different drawables. To add or change left,right,top,bottom image of *CheckedTextView* you should use

```
CheckedTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom)
```

or

```
CheckedTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

and to change CheckMark drawable `CheckedTextView.setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.ic_folder);`

Comment: Yah! You are correct! I tried with setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds method and it is replace the image too. But I could not manage the size of the image here. So I used setCompoundDrawables method. But your answer is also possible to do that. I will up vote you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.ic_folder );

((CheckedTextView) convertView).setCompoundDrawables( img, null, null, null );
```

Comment: @vipulmittal Thanks for the reply. There is a problem to use getContext method inside adapter class (extends with BaseExpandableListAdapter class). I tried to use this "Drawable icon_imageDrawable=parent.getContext().getResources().getDrawable((R.drawable.ic_folder);" But it is not possible to access my image in drawable folder. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: @vipulmittal I could solve the problem of "Drawable icon_imageDrawable=parent.getContext().getResources().getDrawable((R.drawable.ic_folder));" But it is not replace the image. I found out the reason for that too. We have to set bounds for the drawable. BTW your answer was useful for myself to drive to correct path. So don't worry I will up vote it :)

Comment: @IBunny glad to help. You can edit your question and post the final solution you used maybe helpful to others.

Comment: @vipulmittal okay, I will do.